# Should phone app dependent wear os app be released all the time along with Phone app build?

Tags: android, wear-os

I released both phone app and Wear OS app together couple of months ago. After that, I just released couple of phone apps to store without Wear OS build. Now I am not able to find Wear OS app in watch's play store. It's not listing under "Apps on your phone" option.
Do I need to release both Phone app and Wear OS apps together all the time? Even though Wear OS app does not have any updates. Just for the sake of proper versionCode and versionName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should publish it at the same time.  If there is shared code it will make sure it gets the latest version.  And if there are new release requirements like minimum compileSdk/targetSdk (generally Wear is min 30) it is also when you resolve that.

Comment: If I've disabled the Wear OS track for a while and now want to re-enable it, along with releasing an updated Wear OS app that relies on the Phone build, do I still need to submit both builds simultaneously even after Play store  introducing Wear OS only release option?